# Android Retrofit doesn't input data to database

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I've been trying to pass data to database with Retrofit client. It said it succeeded to pass the data, but when i check tha MySQL database it doesn't show that data i just send. Here is my code :

ApiProperties class:

```
public class APIProperties {
    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://10.30.40.32/KPAPI%20v.2/v1/";

    public static UserService getUserService(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(ROOT_URL).create(UserService.class);
    }
}
```

UserInterface interface :

```
import com.telkomuniversity.iflab.spriflab.Model.BookingInfo;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.DELETE;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.PUT;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface UserService {

    @GET("api.php?apicall=getBookings")
    Call<List<BookingInfo>> getBookings();

    @POST("api.php?apicall=createBooking")
    Call<BookingInfo> addBooking(@Body BookingInfo booking);

    @PUT("api.php?apicall=updateStatus")
    Call<BookingInfo> updateStatus(@Path("status") String status, @Body BookingInfo booking);

    @DELETE("api.php?apicall=deleteBooking&={id}")
    Call<BookingInfo> deleteBooking(@Path("id") int id);

}
```

RetrofitClient class :

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Add data method in my Main class :

```
private void addBooking(BookingInfo booking){
    Call<BookingInfo> call = userService.addBooking(booking);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BookingInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BookingInfo> call, Response<BookingInfo> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(FormRuanganActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BookingInfo> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(FormRuanganActivity.this, "ERROR: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure where did i do wrong because it said successfully pass the data (called the response.isSuccessful i believe, and showed a toast said success in it), it still doesn't work

Thank you in advance

Edit : here's my php code of the api

dboperation file :

```
<?php
    class dboperation{
        private $con;

        function __construct(){
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/dbconnect.php';
            $db = new dbconnect();
            $this->con = $db->connect();
        }


        function createBooking($nim, $start, $end, $nama, $alamat, $nohp, $image, 
            $dosen, $ruang, $organisasi, $alasan, $mulai, $selesai){
            // converting string to date
            $timestart = strtotime($start);
            $newformatstart = date('Y-m-d', $timestart);

            $timeend = strtotime($end);
            $newformatend = date('Y-m-d', $timeend);

            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, start, end, nama, alamat, nohp, image, dosen, ruang, organisasi, alasan, mulai, selesai) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $nim, $newformatstart, $newformatend, $nama, $alamat, $nohp, 
                $image,$dosen, $ruang, $organisasi, $alasan, $mulai, $selesai);
            if($stmt->execute())
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        function getBookings(){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT title, start, end, nama, alamat, nohp, image, dosen, ruang, organisasi, alasan, status, mulai, selesai FROM events");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($nim, $start, $end, $nama, $alamat, $nohp, $image, $dosen, $ruang, $organisasi, 
                $alasan, $status, $mulai, $selesai);

            $bookings = array();

            while($stmt->fetch()){
                $booking = array();
                $booking['title'] = $nim;
                $booking['start'] = $start;
                $booking['end'] = $end;
                $booking['nama'] = $nama;
                $booking['alamat'] = $alamat;
                $booking['nohp'] = $nohp;
                $booking['image'] = $image;
                $booking['dosen'] = $dosen;
                $booking['ruang'] = $ruang;
                $booking['organisasi'] = $organisasi;
                $booking['alasan'] = $alasan;
                $booking['status'] = $status;
                $booking['mulai'] = $mulai;
                $booking['selesai'] = $selesai;

                array_push($bookings, $booking);
            }

            return $bookings;
        }

        function updateStatus($id, $status){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE events SET status = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $status, $id);

            if($stmt->execute())
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        function deleteBooking($id){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM events WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

            if($stmt->execute())
                return true;
            return false;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

here's the api.php :

```
<?php

    require_once '../includes/dboperation.php';

    function isParametersAvailable($params){
        $available = true;
        $missingparams = "";

        foreach ($params as $param){
            if(!isset($_POST[$param]) || strlen($_POST[$param])<=0){
                $available = false;
                $missingparams = $missingparams . "," . $param;
            }
        }

        if(!$available){
            $response = array();
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Parameters ' . substr($missingparams, 1, strlen($missingparams)) . ' missing';

            echo json_encode($response);
            die();
        }
    }

    $response = array();

    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        switch($_GET['apicall']){
            case 'createBooking':
                // status dibiarin gaada
                isParametersAvailable(array('title', 'start', 'end', 'nama', 'alamat', 'nohp', 'image', 'dosen',
                    'ruang', 'organisasi', 'alasan', 'mulai', 'selesai'));

                $db = new dboperation();

                $result = $db->createBooking(
                    $_POST['title'],
                    $_POST['start'],
                    $_POST['end'],
                    $_POST['nama'],
                    $_POST['alamat'],
                    $_POST['nohp'],
                    $_POST['image'],
                    $_POST['dosen'],
                    $_POST['ruang'],
                    $_POST['organisasi'],
                    $_POST['alasan'],
                    $_POST['mulai'],
                    $_POST['selesai']);

                if($result){
                    $response['error'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = "Booking added!";
                    $response['bookings'] = $db->getBookings();
                }
                else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "Error occured!";
                }
                break;

            case 'getBookings':
                $db = new dboperation();
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "Requesting to get bookings completed!";
                $response['bookings'] = $db->getBookings();
                break;

            case 'updateStatus':
                isParametersAvailable(array('id', 'status'));
                $db = new dboperation();
                $stat = "";

                if($_POST['status'] == "y"){
                    $stat = "ACCEPTED";
                }
                else if($_POST['status'] == "n"){
                    $stat = "REJECTED";
                }

                $result = $db->updateStatus(
                    $_POST['id'],
                    $stat
                );

                if($result){
                    $response['error'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = "Status updated!";
                    $response['bookings'] = $db->getBookings();
                }
                else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "Error occured!";
                }       
                break;

            case 'deleteBooking':
                if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                    $db = new dboperation();

                    if($db->deleteBooking($_GET['id'])){
                        $response['error'] = false;
                        $response['message'] = "Booking deleted!";
                        $response['bookings'] = $db->getBookings();
                    }
                    else{
                        $response['error'] = true;
                        $response['message'] = "Error occured!";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "No NIM provided!";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Invalid API call";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

[Here's the response i get from onResponse method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivc5b.jpg)

Comment: seems android code is ok.. check php code.. or check in postman if service is working or not.. also if you have developed a php code then post it here

Comment: What's the response `Response<BookingInfo> response` you got?

Comment: @VishvaDave i have add the php code to this thread, and i've tested in postman and it works perfectly, it sends the data to the database as usual

Comment: @salman well when i clicked the submit button it showed the toast with success message in it, so i believe it called the response.isSuccesfull in the if statement in the addBooking method

Comment: @llehcram Would you debug your code and intercept the response?

Comment: @salman i have uploaded a picture showing the response from the onResponse method

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the same db which you used to save data?

Comment: @llehcram As your response says, your client-side acts correctly, there is a problem with your PHP code

Comment: @RahulKumar yes i have, every time i clicked the submit button i always immediately checked the database

Comment: @salman sorry but could you point out which part? i have no idea which part i did wrong, all i know is i've tested on postman and it works fine so i presume that the php code is good, thank you for your answer btw :)